# Where are methods responsible for showing WiFi networks' options?

Tags: android, android-wifi, xposed-framework

I'm going to create xposed module that will add one option to the window which appears when user clicks/holds one of WiFi networks. The dialog box where are located options like "connect", "modify", "cancel".

Where do I find these methods?

Answer (score 0):

```
public void connectTowifi() 
    {
        String ssid = ""// ssid of clicked network
        String pass = "" // pass of clicked network 
        WifiConfiguration wifiConfig = new WifiConfiguration();
        wifiConfig.SSID = "\"" ssid +"\"";
        wifiConfig.preSharedKey  = "\"" + OfflineUtils.generatePassword(ssid)  +  "\"";
        wifiManager.addNetwork(wifiConfig);
        List<WifiConfiguration> list = wifiManager.getConfiguredNetworks();
        for( WifiConfiguration wifiConfiguration : list ) 
        {
            if(wifiConfiguration!=null && wifiConfiguration.SSID != null && wifiConfiguration.SSID.equals(wifiConfig.SSID)) 
            {
                wifiManager.disconnect();
                wifiManager.enableNetwork(wifiConfiguration.networkId, true);
                wifiManager.reconnect();               
            }
        }

    }
```

Similarly for diabling network use 
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager.html#disableNetwork(int)
for forgetiing network 
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager.html#removeNetwork(int)
for disconnect connection:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager.html#disconnect()

For updating netwrok 
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager.html#updateNetwork(android.net.wifi.WifiConfiguration)

For all other methods 
refer to 
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager.html

Comment: I am talking about the dialog, because I want to add one more button to this window. I don't see here any method responsible for calling the dialog.